# Unexpected RollBackException on merge in hibernate (RESOLVED)

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, merge

I'm having `UnexpectedRollBack` exception on a simple merge method with hibernate. I'm using JSP and controller structure.

It should be a simple update, but it returns an exception.

`User.java`:

```
public class user{
   private Integer id;
   String name;
   String active;
}

@Id
@Column(name="ID", unique = true, nullable = false, etc...)
public Integer getId(){return this.id}

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = true, length = 9)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Column(name = "ACTIVE", nullable = true, length = 9)
public String getActive() {
    return this.active;
}

public void setActive(String active) {
    this.active= active;
}
```

Controller:

```
Public class UpdateUserController{

  //Here's the main issue

  User userToUpdate = findUserById("1");

 //user properly recovered from the DB

  userToUpdate.setActive("N");

  //UserService is the class that contains the merging method 
   userService.merge(userToUpdate);

  System.out.println(userToUpdate.getActive());
}
```

Service class:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public user merge(User detachedInstance) {
     try {
        User result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
        return result;
     } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        throw re;
     }
}
```

It's a simple update of a `String`, only one cel in a row, this shouldn't return an exception but it does.

I've seen on some posts that the problem may be caused by the method try to update an element that is currently `null`, that may cause hibernate returns `RollBackException` by default.

I've checked and there is nothing null at the moment of the merge.

Comment: Can you add full stack trace?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I found the problem, I didn't worked becouse the name was created as Varchar (5) and it was trying to update a name with 7 char long.

Now it works fine, i found that on the stack trace. 

Thanks for taking your time to read and help, and sorry for the inconvenience.